# how to use join in yii

Tags: php, yii

How to join using table model
model name:User

Query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT (u.UserID), 
    u.usertypeid, 
    u.UserName
FROM user u, lkusergroup lug, `group` g
WHERE u.userid = lug.userid
AND g.groupid = lug.groupid
AND UserName = 'abcd';
```

Something like this but using model

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('user u')
    ->join('lkusergroup lug', 'u.userid = lug.userid')
    ->join('group g', 'g.groupid = lug.groupid')
    ->where('UserName=:UserName', array(':UserName'=>$this->username))
    ->queryRow();
```

Comment: I'm guessing `with` will not suit your needs?

Comment: Just setup your relations properly for each of your models and use `with` and you'll be just fine. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

Comment: @jhn but its not working..

Comment: Can you show us your config for each tables?